# MySQL can't find my file

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import data into a table from a .csv file, but mysql is having a hard time finding it. When I just have it in my C drive, not in a folder, it finds it fine. When I place the file I want in a folder, then put the file path in my query, it doesn't work.

The query I'm using is:

load data local infile '/C:\file_path'
into table table_name 
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 2 lines;

I have also tried removing 'local' to no avail

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (i.e. unless the [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) SQL mode is enabled), you have to escape backslash characters in [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html).

As documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> Windows path names are specified using forward slashes rather than backslashes. If you do use backslashes, you must double them.

Therefore, use either:

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE 'C:\\file_path' ...
```

Or:

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE 'C:/file_path' ...
```